# recursive definitions using sequences

Tags: discrete-mathematics

lets say I have 2 sequences $$a_0, a_1,\ldots, a_n,\ldots$$ and $$b_0, b_1,\ldots, b_n,\ldots$$ where $$a_k \text{ and } b_k$$ are defined as:

$$ a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n+k \choose 2k}, \quad \quad n\ge 1$$

$$ b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n+k \choose 2k+1}, \quad \quad n\ge 1$$

where $$a_0 = 1,\ b_0 = 0 $$

Show that $$a_n\text{ and }b_n $$ satisfy the following recursive defintions:

$$a_{n+1} = a_n \ + \ b_{n+1}, \quad n\ge0 $$
$$b_{n+1} = a_n \ + \ b_n, \quad n\ge0 $$

not a fan of proofs and I'm unable to find anything in my book either.. thanks

Comment: have tried with small n, i mean n=2,3

Comment: im sorry, i didnt understand that?

Comment: Cardinal was asking if you have checked smaller values of $n$ such as 2,3, et c.

Comment: im having a problem starting it. could you perhaps explain it to me?